# Where to post question about PJL protocol support on specific printer model

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have often questions that fall between software and hardware. My C# code sends print jobs to printers and listens back to the progress messages (using PJL language). Sometimes it stumbles on various issues caused by hardware specific implementation differences. For instance, a printer may receive the commands just fine but does not send any status back. So it is IT topic, but one that does not make sense without programming perspective. Contacting printer manufacturer is usually slow and difficult process.

Where to post such questions? Perhaps I am simply missing "Printer Languages" site (and no, I dont think it would be a thriving community).

Comment: Do you have an example question? [Does Super User satisfy the requirements](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to ask on Stack Overflow or Unix&Linux.SE, example questions:

- Unix and Linux - [How can I check the model of a device connected to a specific COM through a ssh connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524155/261962)
- Stack Overflow - [How do I send data to a modern printer? PDF, PostScript, HPGL, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494505/3648282)

See also their help center topic: "What topics can I ask about here? ":

- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - Hardware specific
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - Programming related